# How to modify a global list through a function without returning a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am learning python. I am supposed to create a function with two parameters. The first of which must be a list and the second an integer. If its not an integer, it must assert an error. the list must add the integer and then sort it out in ascending order. The list passed through the first parameter must be modified but cannot be returned. I am stuck. I dont know how to achieve this without return. Dont give me the answer, just point me in the right direction.

```
def my_insert(lista, num):
    assert (type(num) is int)
    lista.append(num)
    lista = sorted(lista)
     
l = [1, 3, 5]
my_insert(l, 4)
print(l)
```

the print should print [1, 3, 4, 5] and not [1, 3, 5, 4]

Comment: Looks like you want to sort the list inplace... so change: `lista = sorted(lista)` to be `lista.sort()` ?

Comment: Thank you. Works. I did not know you could write that

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked but it's bad practice to use "assert" for program flow, since there are optional optimizations that disable assert statements. Also, you usually want `isinstance(x, y)` rather than `type(x) is y` for polymorphism and duck-typing reasons. You should be able to find more details elsewhere. Good luck.

Comment: @nzbuu My programming course's autocorrector needed assert so i used it. Thank you for the other tip tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "lista.sort()" instead of "sorted(lista)".

```py
def my_insert(lista, num):
        assert (type(num) is int)
        lista.append(num)
        lista.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_insert(lista, num):
    assert type(num) is int
    lista.append(num)
    lista.sort()
```